# Chromium based browsers do not remember cookies on a domain joined server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, chrome, windows-server-2022, microsoft-edge

We have a problem that Chromium based browsers do not remember cookies on a domain joined server.
Can any one point us in the right direction?

What did we do:
We freshly installed the server (2019 or 2022) from VLSC iso.
Create a local user and immediately login as that user.
Setup proxy in the browser and see if it remembers cookies when we browse to a site.
Cookies are stored and we do not get an annoying popup for cookie preferences when we visit a site.
^^^so this step is wanted behavior.

In AD we create a new Test OU with no policies and disable inheritance. We put the computername in the Test OU.
Installed RDS role.
We make the server member of AD and it is in the Test OU.
We check the server with "gpresult /h /test.html" and RSOP.msc if any policies are loaded and this is not the case.
We login to the server with a domain account (regular or DA does not matter for end result) and browse to the same site we used as a local test user. We get a popup to set our cookie preferences.
When we close the browser and go back to the site we get the prompt again.  <-- unwanted behavior

When we check if the cookies file is changed this is not the case. It is 20KB and does not change.
If we remove the file and start the browser the file is recreated and has the same size but it is never updated after.

Cookie location: C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Network

We have tested and can replicate this behavior in Chromium based browsers:
Chrome Enterprise, Edge

Firefox is ok.

Comment: What is the result when a local account is used?

Comment: @GregAskew Please read first step. That is what we did. It works. It also works after domjoin and then switch to the local user.
A domain user doesnt work. Same system, clean profile.

Comment: Are there any settings in HKCU\Software\Policies\Google ?

Comment: @GregAskew No there are no settings at HKCU\Software\Policies\Google . Also not under HKLM.
In fact the Google location is not created.

1 thing i forgot to mention is that the RDS role is installed on the server.

Comment: Given this is a remote desktop host, you may want to verify the location/validity of the various user profile/home directory folders. Also use Process Monitor when testing Edge to see if it is accessing a Cookies file, and the location.

Comment: The rofile is not temporary, right?